# iOS app: how to use kingfisher/sdwebimage to download aws s3 image

Tags: swift, amazon-s3, swiftui, sdwebimage, kingfisher

i want to show images from aws s3 protected folder in collectionview or list in my swiftui project using kingfisher. But i couldn't find a solution to show the images as aws requires additional headers to be included in request. I tried adding custom header mentioned in Cheatsheet, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose what key Kingfisher uses for the cache. So, create a presigned s3 url, then when loading the image use your s3 key as the cache rather then the full presigned url.

```
            let getPreSignedURLRequest = AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest()
            getPreSignedURLRequest.bucket = media.bucket
            getPreSignedURLRequest.key = media.key
            getPreSignedURLRequest.httpMethod = .GET
            getPreSignedURLRequest.expires = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3600)  // Change the value of the expires time interval as required
            AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder.default().getPreSignedURL(getPreSignedURLRequest).continueWith { (task:AWSTask<NSURL>) -> Any? in
                if let error = task.error as NSError? {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                    return nil
                }
                if let presignedURL = task.result {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.imageView.kf.indicatorType = .activity
                        let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: presignedURL.absoluteString!)!, cacheKey: media.key)
                        self.imageView.kf.setImage(with: resource)
                    }
                }
                return nil
            }
```

Comment: will this work if my s3 bucket is protected? and what is media key here?